# Trigger whenever a value in a view has changed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a SQL view, which resolves some foreign key dependencies. The View looks like this:

```
id | title | plantName | customerName | lastUpdated
```

Where plantName and customerName are 2 resolved values of a foreign key.

There are 3 Tables in total:

```
Table 1
id | name | surname | idTable2 | idTable3 | lastUpdated

Table 2
id | plantName

Table 3
id | firstName | lastName
```

What i want to archieve is a trigger which updates the `lastUpdated` column in the View everytime a row shows another value.
The Problem here is, that `lastUpdated` inside the View should also be updated when a foreign key changes it's value.

Example view Output:

```
1 | hotel | mock | meier | 2020-02-26 10:03:03.817
2 | hotel | raddison | mueller | 2020-02-26 10:04:03.000
```

Let's say I'll update `Table 2` and update "raddison" to "mercure hotel". The View will look like this afterwards:

```
1 | hotel | mock | meier | 2020-02-26 10:03:03.817
2 | hotel | mercure hotel | mueller | 2020-02-26 10:04:03.000
```

I now want that the `lastUpdated` Column in the View of row 2 representing the datetime where the foreign key has changed. 
Desired output:

```
1 | hotel | mock | meier | 2020-02-26 10:03:03.817
2 | hotel | mercure hotel | mueller | 2020-02-26 13:44:03.000
```

Is there any way to archieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using front end programming or plain sql?

Comment: Only one of your tables has "last updated". Is that an oversight?

Comment: No thats not an oversight. The view has it initially from Table 1, but my aim is to only overwrite the value of "last updated" in the view.

Comment: Views don't *store* any data of their own (outside of indexed views, which effectively have *caches*, not independent data). You can't update the "last updated" of the view. It doesn't exist.

Comment: Damn, that's what I expected.

Comment: It helps no one to imply some sort of botanical schema when your sample data implies hotels.

Comment: So, you want to update the "last_updated" column in table 1 whenever a value changes in tables 1, 2 or 3, and include that "last_updated" value in your view?

Comment: Sounds like you just want an update trigger on table1 so that when that row is changed it updates the last_updated column.

Comment: You can create `update` triggers on all three tables and they can all update `Table 1`. Since there is no view involved it would have to be based on the relations, e.g. a change in `Table 2` may effect 7 rows in `Table 1` that share the same plant because there is no way to differentiate between them within the trigger.

Comment: Can you change the underlying table structure?  If so, you could put a `lastUpdated` column on all the tables and then return the most recent `lastUpdated` in the view.

Comment: @iamdave I can change it. How do I then use the mostReced lastUpdated column in the view?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Exactly.

Comment: Do you already have the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you confirmed that you want the following:

> you want to update the "last_updated" column in table 1 whenever a
>   value changes in tables 1, 2 or 3, and include that "last_updated"
>   value in your view

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634918/how-do-i-add-a-last-modified-and-created-column-in-a-sql-server-table) shows you how to create a trigger to update a column when a record is modified.

You will need to create that trigger on tables 1, 2 and 3, and the update statement should update table 1's `lastUpdated` column.

Alternatively, you could create a `lastUpdated` on all 3 tables, and select the highest value in your view.